# Espresso - check which Activity is opened using intent on button press?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

**Is it possible to trace which Activity is opened after a certain button is pressed?**
I have a test in which, **when a button is clicked / pressed**, it **sends a request to the server**. Till the time the request is sent, **it opens an Activity**. **To verify the successful execution** of the test, I need to check what is the open Activity.
 
Example of my test:

Check which Intent is opened in Espresso ---

```
 private void startTest() {
    recreateAuthData(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), "d78269d9-9e00-4b8d-9242-815204b0a2f6", "3f32da21-914d-4adc-b6a1-891b842a2972");

    InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getSharedPreferences(ActivitySplashScreen.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(ActivitySplashScreen.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, ActivitySplashScreen.getAppVersion(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())).commit();
    InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getSharedPreferences(ActivitySplashScreen.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(ActivitySplashScreen.PROPERTY_REG_ID, "testKey").commit();

    mActivityRule.launchActivity(setIntent());
    // inputPinCode("2794");
}

@Test
public void testIdent() {
    startTest();
    onView(withText("ПРО")).perform(click());
    putDelay(500);
    onView(withId(R.id.get_pro)).perform(click());
    onView(withText("Авторизация по паспортным данным")).perform(click());
    putDelay(500);
    closeSoftKeyboard();
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_goto_passport)).perform(click());
    onView(withHint("Серия и номер паспорта")).perform(replaceText("9894657891"));
    onView(withHint("Дата выдачи паспорта")).perform(replaceText("17032014"));
    onView(withHint("Дата рождения")).perform(replaceText("31091994"));
    onView(withHint("СНИЛС")).perform(replaceText("54665285919"));
    putDelay(500);
    Log.d("TestWidget", hasComponent(hasShortClassName("ActivityMain")).toString());
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_next)).perform(click());
    // some code which check which activity is display now
    putDelay(500);

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Whether it is possible to trace which the Activity opened after
>   pressing the button?

Check `espresso-intents` library:

### Configuration

Add to your `app/build.gradle` these lines:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
```

> NOTICE: `espresso-intents` won't run without `espresso-core`, `runner` or `rules` libs.

You may also need to change `ActivityTestRule<>` to `IntentsTestRule` as it is described here:

> #### IntentsTestRule
>
> Use IntentsTestRule instead of ActivityTestRule when using
>   Espresso-Intents. IntentsTestRule makes it easy to use
>   Espresso-Intents APIs in functional UI tests. This class is an
>   extension of ActivityTestRule, which initializes Espresso-Intents
>   before each test annotated with @Test and releases Espresso-Intents
>   after each test run. The activity will be terminated after each test
>   and this rule can be used in the same way as ActivityTestRule.
>
> From:
>   https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/

Example code (click on button to launch new activity)

Here's a solution using `espresso-intents` for similar problem:

> An example test with intent stubbing:
>
> ```
> @Test
>  public void testActivityResultIsHandledProperly() {
>    // Build a result to return when a particular activity is launched.
>    Intent resultData = new Intent();
>    String phoneNumber = "123-345-6789";
>    resultData.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);
>    ActivityResult result = new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
>
>    // Set up result stubbing when an intent sent to "contacts" is seen.
>    intending(toPackage("com.android.contacts")).respondWith(result));
>
>    // User action that results in "contacts" activity being launched.
>    // Launching activity expects phoneNumber to be returned and displays it on the screen.
>    user.clickOnView(system.getView(R.id.pickButton));
>
>    // Assert that data we set up above is shown.
>    assertTrue(user.waitForText(phoneNumber));
>  }
> ```
>
> From:
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.html

Additional resources:

- [[Android Developers] Espresso Intents Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.html)
- [[Github || Google Samples] Basic sample for Espresso Intents](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample)
- [[Github] Android Espresso Intent Sample](https://github.com/barend/android-espresso-intent-sample)
- [Testing for Android Intents using Espresso](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/06/11/testing-for-android-intents-using-espresso/)
- [[Gist] Example of how to use espresso-intents in Android tests](https://gist.github.com/vgonda/1b2520619052cc5bf9b8) - source code for link above

Answer (score 22):

To actually match a started activity with Espresso intents you need to check for the component of the new intent:

```java
intended(hasComponent(NewActivity.class.getName()));
```

Make sure to call `Intents.init()` in the setup and `Intents.release()` in teardown to be able to record intents with Espresso.

Comment: This actually checks whether the activity is present in the list of recorded intents. And this would also throw an error if the same activity was opened earlier. So be cautious to use it.