# How to validate whether opened correct activity - Espresso

Tags: android-espresso

I created android UI test with espresso and done Button click and opening an Activity. Now I want to validate whether opened correct activity or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [espresso-intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/) to validate that.

The usage is:

`intended(hasComponent(NewActivity.class.getName()));`

You can read this thread for more details on that:
[Espresso - check which Activity is opened using intent on button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250754/espresso-check-which-activity-is-opened-using-intent-on-button-press/39262599#39262599)

Answer (score 0):

You want get the instance of activity rule which you have register and compare it with the activity which you want.

```
// Define activity rule
    @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>
                MainActivity.class);


    // compare activity rule activity with the activity you want to check.

    Assert.assertEquals(mActivityRule.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: `getActivity()` returns the activity that the testrule has launched. This assertion will ALWAYS pass

Comment: @Be_Negative These is the only way i guess you can validate these

Comment: But you are not validating anything here. What you are validating is that the activity in the test rule is indeed the activity that you want. What is the point? :)